# AWS Lambda- get html of the website

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create function in AWS Lambda which returns html of the given website. That is my code:

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var util = require("util"),
http = require("http");

var options = {
    host: "www.nyuad.nyu.edu/en/news-events/abu-dhabi-events.html",
    port: 80,
    path: "/"
};

var content = "";   

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        content += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function () {
        util.log(content);
        callback(null, content);
    });
});

req.end();
};
```

It works perfectly for 'www.google.com' as a *host* parameter in *options* but when I try with more complicated, similar to the given one in the code, I get an error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.nyuad.nyu.edu/en/news-events/abu-dhabi-events.html www.nyuad.nyu.edu/en/news-events/abu-dhabi-events.html:80

at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), you'll see:

- host: domain name or IP address of the server to issue the request to
- path: request path, defaults to '/'. Should include query string if any. E.G. '/index.html?page=12'